# Why padding not working in my JSF DataTable?

Tags: html, css

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong but my padding doesn't work:

[image]

Padding is set to parent div and overflow to hidden.

Code:

```html
<thead id="j_idt248-j_idt249_head">
   <tr role="row">
      <th id="j_idt248-j_idt249-j_idt251" class="ui-state-default ui-sortable-column ui-filter-column serviceTypeColumn" role="columnheader" aria-label="Request type: activate to sort column ascending" scope="col" tabindex="0" aria-sort="other"><span class="ui-column-title">Request type</span><span class="ui-sortable-column-icon ui-icon ui-icon-carat-2-n-s"></span><label id="j_idt248-j_idt249-j_idt251-filter_label" for="j_idt248-j_idt249-j_idt251-filter" class="ui-helper-hidden">Filter by Request type</label><input id="j_idt248-j_idt249-j_idt251-filter" name="j_idt248-j_idt249-j_idt251-filter" class="ui-column-filter ui-inputfield ui-inputtext ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" value="" autocomplete="off" aria-labelledby="j_idt248-j_idt249-j_idt251-filter_label" role="textbox" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false"></th>
      <th id="j_idt248-j_idt249-j_idt253" class="ui-state-default ui-sortable-column ui-filter-column originalServiceTypeColumn" role="columnheader" aria-label="Original service: activate to sort column ascending" scope="col" tabindex="0"><span class="ui-column-title">Original service</span><span class="ui-sortable-column-icon ui-icon ui-icon-carat-2-n-s"></span><label id="j_idt248-j_idt249-j_idt253-filter_label" for="j_idt248-j_idt249-j_idt253-filter" class="ui-helper-hidden">hidden</label><input id="j_idt248-j_idt249-j_idt253-filter" name="j_idt248-j_idt249-j_idt253-filter" class="ui-column-filter ui-inputfield ui-inputtext ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" value="" autocomplete="off" aria-labelledby="j_idt248-j_idt249-j_idt253-filter_label" role="textbox" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false"></th>
      <th id="j_idt248-j_idt249-j_idt255" class="ui-state-default ui-sortable-column ui-filter-column startTimeColumn" role="columnheader" aria-label="Start time: activate to sort column ascending" scope="col" tabindex="0"><span class="ui-column-title">Start time</span><span class="ui-sortable-column-icon ui-icon ui-icon-carat-2-n-s"></span><label id="j_idt248-j_idt249-j_idt255-filter_label" for="j_idt248-j_idt249-j_idt255-filter" class="ui-helper-hidden">Filter by Start time</label><input id="j_idt248-j_idt249-j_idt255-filter" name="j_idt248-j_idt249-j_idt255-filter" class="ui-column-filter ui-inputfield ui-inputtext ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" value="" autocomplete="off" aria-labelledby="j_idt248-j_idt249-j_idt255-filter_label" role="textbox" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false"></th>
      <th id="j_idt248-j_idt249-j_idt257" class="ui-state-default ui-filter-column" role="columnheader" aria-label="VIN" scope="col"><span class="ui-column-title">VIN</span><label id="j_idt248-j_idt249-j_idt257-filter_label" for="j_idt248-j_idt249-j_idt257-filter" class="ui-helper-hidden">Filter by VIN</label><input id="j_idt248-j_idt249-j_idt257-filter" name="j_idt248-j_idt249-j_idt257-filter" class="ui-column-filter ui-inputfield ui-inputtext ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" value="" autocomplete="off" aria-labelledby="j_idt248-j_idt249-j_idt257-filter_label" role="textbox" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false"></th>
   </tr>
</thead>
```

CSS:

```css
    .ui-datatable-tablewrapper tr {
      padding: 0 4px;
    }
```

Comment: can you please share your source code you are trying with ?

Comment: `tr` won't have a *parent `div`*, otherwise you have invalid HTML.

Comment: @RamChander I can't because it's secret :/

Comment: @Johnny97 : you may try putting together a basic example without the "secret", so that you can share it.

Comment: We can't help you without a [mcve]. We don't need all your code, just an example that represents the problem.

Comment: I've added some code snipet. I've set the padding to the <tr> element.

Comment: Padding doesn't work on table rows. Put the padding on the ths instead or use a border-spacing on the table.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Mr Lister for this tip. This is how I've handled the situation a little bit tricky but working:

```css
.ui-datatable-tablewrapper tr td:first-child {
    padding-left: 4px;
}

.ui-datatable-tablewrapper tr td:last-child {
    padding-right: 4px;
}
```